# How to check memory allocated to open files in a process

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, memory-leaks

The scenario is that I'm running a test program which grows to 8GB in size, and then a series of asserts are done via [Check](http://check.sourceforge.net).

I can see my process grow to 8GB in size in '*top*' and I see my system memory grow accordingly. However, when a large number of asserts are done afterwards, I see **VIRT stop growing** as expected, and I see my **total used** memory continue to increase as Check is going through the asserts. So according to top there's no more memory being given to any processes, but I something is still chewing through memory.

I sort top by memory usage and see nothing else is reserving memory. Eventually I hit 100% swap and physical memory usage and the process gets killed.

Note that Check will fork each 'test' into its own process. When I break the test program (w/ ctrl+c), I still see the process in top, and its VIRT still reads 8GB.

I believe memory is being eaten by Check, because this behavior doesn't happen when I take out all the asserts.  I saw in Check that a tmpfile() is created and used to track the last assert that happened and I see /tmp growing as the assert phase begins.  If I modify Check code to write to a file in /tmp (instead of using tmpfile()), I see that file grows to be GBs big.

1) Why doesn't the virtual address space being taken up by the **open file** show up as part of the **process' used memory**? Note that Check forks off each 'test'.  Also, even though swap is full, shouldn't unused parts of the file just get paged back out to memory? (writes are done via fwrite, not mmap)

2) A secondary question, I haven't used tmpfile() before, but **why doesn't any file show up in /tmp when tmpfile()** is invoked? If it is because the file is unlinked immediately, does that mean any unlinked file won't show up in the filesystem? (My understanding of what unlink does is also rudimentary).

edit: I'm using Arch Linux w/ kernel 4.0.5-1 and procps-ng version 3.3.10

Comment: Opening a file does not automatically load the whole file content into  the process address space. That is, there is no virtual memory allocated for the contents of the file simply by opening a file (there is some book keeping memory needed of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small experiment shows that yes, because tmpfile is created in /tmp, it is held purely in memory, and because I was running out of memory, my program got killed.  Because the program had the last open file descriptor, the file is deleted(freed out of my tmpfs) after the program was killed.  Because /**tmp** exists only in memory as a tmpfs, it can't be 'paged out' to disk because the filesystem itself exists only in memory, and swap was also full, hence the OOM error.

By performing the same experiment with a file in **/var/tmp**, which is instead on disk, no extra memory was being taken up so I didn't get this error.

While I couldn't view this behavior with **top**, **free -h** showed the memory being taken up under *shared* and *buff/cache*.
To narrow down the exact culprit, I used:

```
lsof | awk '$5 == "REG"' | sort -n -r -k 7,7 | head -n 5
```

from https://serverfault.com/questions/207100/how-can-i-find-phantom-storage-usage

Note that the above will not work if /tmp is already full. 
So *the open file was not the problem*, i.e. buffering was not the problem. The problem was that the file existed in a tmpfs.

To answer my **#2**, the file doesn't show up because it was 'deleted' when it was unlinked with tmpfile():

```
$ lsof | awk '$5 == "REG"' | sort -n -r -k 7,7 | head -n 5
toy       13624       me    3u      REG               0,33 4294963200   12505948 /tmp/tmpf0W4HOM (deleted)
```